# Samsung Kies version for both old and new android versions?

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, device-firmware

A friend gave me his older Samsung tablet to upgrade since it kept failing with the OTA update, so like indicated I will try KIES first for updating the device.

However I also have 3 newer android (lollipop) phones... so ... what is the advised way? Deinstall version 3 then install version 2.6 (to work with older android versions) and after that deinstall version 2.6 and reinstall version 3 (for my newer android versions) ?

Anyone dealt with this / has a setup for this?

*update* I installed smart switch which seems to work for all. It calls ODIN and stuff seems to work.

Comment: You might want to go the hard way, downloading the ROM manually and flashing it manually. Please mention the device model, full Android version and whether it is rooted, has a custom recovery, etc or not.

Comment: *`update`* `I installed smart switch which seems to work for all. It calls ODIN and stuff seems to work.` -- Please answer your question using the answer field.

Answer (score 0):

If i underestand your question exactly,

***OTA update*** is not suggested.

for many reasons, if the current installed rom from another region, maybe you cannot update it with `OTA`.
(perhaps, android update for your region rom not availabe)

it's better to download the Rom from Official and truted link and flash it on your phone for update.

hope this helps.